# Unlimited horizontal UIScrollView space while conserving memory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm implementing UITableView and UITableViewCell subclasses. These objects will draw lines on the screen, but also allow the user to zoom in.  When the user "zooms in" the lines scale up horizontally, but not vertically.  This in turn causes my table content width to increase by 50% with each zoom-in.

The problem that I'm having is that if I zoom-in 12 times, the App runs out of memory and crashes.  Zooming in 12 times increases the table/cell dimensions from 300 points to say 35000 points.  Even if I do nothing in drawRect, it appears the mere size of the table view alone will crash the App.

Has anyone solved this type of issue before?  I tried searching but didn't find anything similar.  I'm fine with faking a view size.  I'd like to just draw 2x the visible space and then redraw when some scroll event happens.  This seems to be manageable.  Has anyone done this with UIScrollView? What is the right way to achieve virtually unlimited horizontal space without running out of memory?

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand but couldn't you use a paged UIScrollView this will give you 'unlimited' horizontal screen space!